# HTML Email table displays weird border on certain screen sizes

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

I am developing an HTML email and I am getting a weird issue; when viewing the email in chrome with responsive mode on there is a faint border on some of the cells.  I am not sure what is causing it, none of the cells have any border and it only shows when the screen size you have set in chrome is such that the email is full width.  I have tested the email using email on acid testing previews and the issue is showing on iPhone tests. Anyone know what's causing this and how to fix it? [image: screenshot]

The issue does not show in code pen, I am just using it to share the html:
https://codepen.io/jmona789/pen/ZELjrOv

Relevent portion of html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Some resets and issue fixes */
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text;
            size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .backgroundTable {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
             !important;
        }

        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .ExternalClass * {
            line-height: 115%;
        }

        /* End reset */

        @import url(https://imcsecuresftp.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Arboria-Bold_1.otf);

        /*Calling our web font*/
        /*==============REGULAR NOTATION===================*/
        @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            .full-column {
                float: none !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                display: table !important;
            }

            .center-on-mobile {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            .column-td {
                padding: 0px 24px !important;
            }

            .column-td-right-only {
                padding: 0px 24px 0px 0px !important;
            }

            .column-td-left-only {
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 24px !important;
            }

            .mobile-line-br {
                line-height: 30px !important;
            }

            .hide {
                display: none !important;
            }

            .show {
                display: block !important;
            }

            table.full-width-table {
                height: px;
            }

            img.full-width {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
            }
        }

        /* Colors
                * #6caae3 = Dark Blue
                * #6caae3 = Light Blue
                * #f3f3f3 = Light Grey - Background
                * #333333 = Dark Grey - Body Copy
                * #555759 = Sub Header Grey
                * #ee3134 = Red
                --------------------------------------------- */

        @font-face {
            src: url("http://imc-secure.com/immunoCAP/Fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-MdCn.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-MdCn";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtIt.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtIt";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-It.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-It";
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/imcsecuresftp/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman";
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        @font-face {
            src: url("https://imcsecuresftp.s3.amazonaws.com/fonts/Arboria-Bold_1.otf") format("truetype");
            font-family: "Arboria-Bold";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        [style*="Arboria-Bold"] {
            font-family: 'Arboria-Bold', Helvetica-Bold, "Arial Black", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv"] {
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md"] {
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd"] {
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman"] {
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt"] {
            font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtIt"] {
            //font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-LtIt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
            font-style: italic;

        }

        [style*="HelveticaNeueLTStd-It"] {
            //font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-It', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        /* Client-specific Styles */
        table {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
        body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }

        /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
        }

        /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.*/
        #backgroundTable {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
            line-height: 100% !important;
        }

        img {
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }

        a img {
            border: none;
        }

        .image_fix {
            display: block;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

        /*STYLES*/
        table.full {
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
        }

        .appleLinks a {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .appleLinksGray a {
            color: #a7a9ac;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        /*IPHONE STYLES*/
        @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table#DesktopOnly {
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                height: 0px !important;
                mso-hide: all !important;
                max-height: 0 !important;
                overflow: hidden !important;
            }

            table#FooterDesktopOnly {
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                height: 0px !important;
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                height: 0px !important;
                mso-hide: all !important;
                max-height: 0 !important;
                overflow: hidden !important;
            }

            #image1 {
                width: 390px;
                height: 314px;
            }

            a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
                color: inherit !important;
                text-decoration: none !important;
                font-size: inherit !important;
                font-family: inherit !important;
                font-weight: inherit !important;
                line-height: inherit !important;
            }

            a[href^="tel"],
            a[href^="sms"] {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #0a8cce;
                /* or whatever your want */
                pointer-events: none;
                cursor: default;
            }

            table.devicewidth {
                width: 390px !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /*tr.devicewidth {width: 390px!important;text-align:center!important;}*/
            /*td.devicewidth {width: 390px!important;text-align:center!important;}*/
            table.devicewidthinner {
                width: 360px !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            table#footer {
                width: 360px !important;
            }

            table#HeaderTable {
                width: 360px !important;
            }

            img.colimg2 {
                width: 280px !important;
                height: 140px !important;
            }

            td#FooterTD {
                width: 255px !important;
            }

            br#MobileOnlyBR {
                display: block !important;
            }

            table#DesktopOnly {
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                height: 0px !important;
            }

            tr#DesktopOnly {
                max-height: 0px !important;
                height: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                line-height: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
                margin: 0px !important;
                width: 0px !important;
            }

            td#DesktopOnly {
                max-height: 0px !important;
                height: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                line-height: 0px !important;
                padding: 0px !important;
                margin: 0px !important;
                width: 0px !important;
            }

            tr#MobileOnlyTR {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: table-row !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
            }

            td#MobileOnlyTD {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
            }

            div#MobileOnlyDiv {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
            }

            table#MobileOnly {
                width: 390px !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: table !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                position: relative !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            table#MobileOnlyInnerTable {
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: table !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                position: relative !important;
                /*margin-left: auto!important;
                        margin-right: auto!important;*/
            }

            table#MobileOnlyTable {
                width: 100% !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: left !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                position: relative !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: left !important;
                display: table !important;
            }

            /* --------------- Responsive Footer Code Start --------------------------------- */
            table#HeaderTable {
                width: 360px !important;
            }

            td.MobileHeight20 {
                height: 20px !important;
            }

            td#FooterMobileText {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px !important;
                line-height: 14px !important;
                text-align: left !important;
                color: #888888 !important;
                padding-bottom: 20px !important;
            }

            table#FooterDesktopOnly {
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
                height: 0px !important;
            }

            table#MobileOnlyFooter {
                width: 390px !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                position: relative !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            table#MobileOnlyFooter2 {
                width: 390px !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                position: relative !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            div#FooterSocialImages {
                width: 100% !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                height: 100% !important;
                min-height: 100% !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            div#FooterSocialImages2 {
                width: 100% !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                height: 100% !important;
                min-height: 100% !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            table#FooterSocialImagesTable {
                width: 100% !important;
                min-width: 390px !important;
                overflow: visible !important;
                float: none !important;
                display: block !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                height: 100% !important;
                min-height: 100% !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            img#FooterLogoMobile {
                width: 180px !important;
                position: relative !important;
                margin-top: 13px !important;
                margin-left: 105px !important;
                margin-bottom: 13px !important;
                margin-right: 105px !important;
            }

            /* --------------- Responsive Footer Code End --------------------------------- */
        }

        table.em_show,
        tr.em_show,
        td.em_show,
        br.em_show,
        span.em_show {
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            line-height: 0px;
            mso-hide: all;
            max-height: 0px;
            mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            td.em_show_nonText {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
            }

            table.em_show,
            tr.em_show,
            td.em_show,
            br.em_show {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: table-cell !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
            }

            span.em_show {
                overflow: visible !important;
                display: inline !important;
                line-height: 100% !important;
                mso-hide: none !important;
                max-height: none !important;
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
            }

            td.em_align_center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            td.em_align_right {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            table.em_hide,
            tr.em_hide,
            td.em_hide,
            br.em_hide,
            span.em_hide {
                display: none !important;
                overflow: hidden;
                line-height: 0px;
                mso-hide: all;
                max-height: 0px;
                font-size: 0px;
                mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
            }
        }

        /*==============END REGULAR NOTATION===================*/
        /*prevent superscripts from pushing line above them*/
        sup {
            line-height: 0;
            /*vertical-align: baseline;*/
            /*position: relative;*/
            /*top: -0.4em;*/
        }

        sub {
            line-height: 0;
        }

        /*  @media only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:650px) {
                    table[class=em_wrapper] {
                        width: 100% !important;
                    }
                }*/
        @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table[class=em_wrapper] {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table.em_wrapper {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width:1px) {

            /*gmail doesnt support media queries so this table will only show on gmail*/
            .gmail-app-fix,
            table.gmail-app-fix {
                display: none !important;
                overflow: hidden;
                line-height: 0px;
                mso-hide: all;
                max-height: 0px;
                font-size: 0px;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body style="margin:0;">
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;margin-right:100%;">
        Explore allergy diagnostic resources
    </div>
<span style="display:none !important;visibility:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">
<!--EOA COMMENT: This snippet of white space has been added to ensure short preview text does not run into the following text of your email.-->
&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</span>
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;margin-right:100%;">
    </div>

    <center>

        <table style="width:600px; margin:auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" width="600" role="presentation">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="width:600px; margin:auto;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" width="600" role="presentation">
                        <tr>
                            <!--[if mso]>
                                <td width="3%" class="em_hide" style="width:3%;background-color:#098fa1;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <![endif]-->
                            <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                <td width="50" class="em_hide" style="width:50px;background-color:#098fa1;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                            <td width="25" class="em_show" style="display: none;overflow:hidden;line-height:0px;mso-hide:all;max-height:0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;width:25px;background-color:#098fa1;">&nbsp;</td>


                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;" role="presentation">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom:0px;background-color:#098fa1;" bgcolor="#098fa1">
                                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;background-color:#098fa1" role="presentation">
                                                <tr>

                                                    <td>
                                                        <table class="full-column" style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:100%;background-color:#098fa1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" role="presentation">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="45" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:45px; line-height:45px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                </tr>



                                                                <tr style="background-color:#098fa1">
                                                                    <td width="498" class="column-td " style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0px; width:498px;
                                                                                    font-family: Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;font-size:20px; color:#ffffff; line-height: 30px; mso-line-height: exactly; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;background-color:#098fa1" valign="top">
                                                                        <div style="background-color:#098fa1">
                                                                            <b style="font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;">

                                                                                COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY 

                                                                            </b>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="21" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:21px; line-height:21px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr style="background-color:#098fa1">
                                                                    <td width="498" class="column-td " style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0px; width:498px;
                                                                                    font-family: Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman;font-size:16px; color:#ffffff; line-height: 22px; mso-line-height: exactly; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;background-color:#098fa1" valign="top">
                                                                        <div style="background-color:#098fa1">

                                                                            COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY 

                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="31" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:31px; line-height:31px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr style="background-color:#098fa1">
                                                                    <td width="498" class="column-td " style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0px; width:498px;
                                                                                    font-family: Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;font-size:18px; color:#ffffff; line-height: 24px; mso-line-height: exactly; vertical-align: middle; text-align: left;background-color:#098fa1" valign="top">
                                                                        <div style="background-color:#098fa1">
                                                                            <b style="font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd;">

                                                                                COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY COPY 

                                                                            </b>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>



                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="15" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:15px; line-height:15px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom:0px;background-color:#098fa1;" bgcolor="#098fa1">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                                                <tr>

                                                    <td class="column-td">
                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                                <td id="MobileOnlyTD" align="left" style="max-height: 0px;height: 0px; display: none; line-height: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 0px;">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/?elqTrackId=1d6421fd2ca1472bb6411c63a31fa818" style="background-color:#E71316;
                                                                                    border:1px solid #E71316;border-radius:1px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:166px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">
                                                                            <span style="position:relative;top:2px;">
                                                                                FPO CTA
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                <td id="DesktopOnly" align="left">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <!--[if mso]>
                                                                                        <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://example.com/" style="height:30px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:166px;" arcsize="1%" strokecolor="#E71316"
                                                                                         fillcolor="#E71316">
                                                                                            <w:anchorlock/>
                                                                                            <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md;font-size:16px;">
                                                                                                <span style='position:relative;top:2px;'>
                                                                                                        FPO CTA
                                                                                                </span>
                                                                                            </center>
                                                                                        </v:roundrect>
                                                                                    <![endif]-->
                                                                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                                                                        <a target="_blank" href="https://example.com/?elqTrackId=9f1232b523164fd4adf1e73ba8201850" style="background-color:#E71316;
                                                                                        border:1px solid #E71316;border-radius:1px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:Helvetica, HelveticaArial, sans-serif, HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md;font-size:16px;line-height:30px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:166px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">
                                                                            <span style="position:relative;top:2px;">
                                                                                FPO CTA
                                                                            </span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                        <!--<![endif]-->
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="216" class="em_hide" style="width:216px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;margin:0;padding:0;">&nbsp;</td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="50" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:50px; line-height:50px;background-color:#098fa1;" bgcolor="#098fa1">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
```

Comment: I tried to inspect your code - but the tables are so deeply nested and your html is so extremely polluted with inline styles, that i gave up - sorry...

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't replicate the issue. There is quite a lot of redundant code (e.g. fonts on elements not holding text, padding:0 on element with no padding) in there as well as empty properties included in your inline styles (e.g. height:px;) that should be cleaned out. On top of this, there are a lot of extra line breaks between elements and line breaks in amongst your CSS properties. That makes for really tough debugging unfortunately.

Comment: biberman, that's how all html emails are built

Answer (score 0):

The email is scaling down on phones, causing this, because you have things like width="498" and other wide elements (mobiles can get down to 280px--including all padding). Make the email responsive and the issue should go away. I suggest a complete rebuild, sorry - the code is much too complex for what it needs to be. There are plenty of HTML Email examples and tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you haven't applied `border:none` to `table` (just `border-spacing: 0;`) - I think you should add that.